# grouping and summarizing the rows in a big text file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a big text file like this example:

`example`:

```
chr11   314980  314981  63  IFITM1  -131
chr11   315025  315026  54  IFITM1  -86
chr5    315085  315086  118 AHRR    -53011
chr16   316087  316088  56  ITFG3   -86
chr16   316088  316089  90  ITFG3   -131
chr11   319672  319673  213 IFITM3  -131
chr11   319674  319675  514 IFITM3  -164
```

I want to group the rows based on the 6th column and sum the values
from the 4th column for every group. the new file would have 2
columns. 1st column would be the group and the 2nd column would be sum
(sum of values from column 4 from similar groups). the expected output
would look like this:

`expected output`:

```
-131    366
-86     110
-53011  118
-164    514
```

I am trying to do that in `awk` using the following code.

```
sort myfile.txt | awk -F'\t' '{ sub(/..$/,"**",$6) }1' OFS='\t' | awk '{print $1 "\t" $2}' > outfile.txt
```

but actually it returns an empty file. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: The only way that script would output an empty file is if you input an empty file so either your input file is empty or the script you posted isn't the script you're running or you are not getting an empty output file.. Also, what are you hoping that `sub(/..$/,"**",$6)` will do for you?

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea what you are thinking with your code: why you are replacing the last 2 chars on the line with asterisks? why aren't you doing any addition anywhere? why do you sort (by column 1) first?

```
awk -F'\t' '
    {sum[$6] += $4} 
    END {for (key in sum) {print key, sum[key]}}
' file | column -t
```

Answer (score 4):

Use an associative array:

```
awk '{a[$NF]+=$4}END{for (i in a){print i, a[i]}}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with sorted output, you don't need arrays:

```
sort -k6n file |
awk -F'\t' '
    grp != $6 {
        grp = $6
        printf "%s%s%s%s", sum, sep, grp, FS
        sum = 0
        sep = ORS
    } { sum += $4 } END { print sum }'
```